# « Connecté », « relié », « raccordé » ou autre ?

Tags: choix-de-mot, formulation-idiomatique, formulation, reformulation

> Les deux nouveaux quartiers en développement dont je te parle sont situés dans la même zone urbaine, l’un étant situé au nord de l’autre. C’est le même promoteur qui est derrière ces deux éco-quartiers, l’un débouche sur la rue Notre-Monsieur et l’autre sur la rue St-Christian. Il existe une voie ferrée entre les deux développements et pour des considérations qui se rapportent à la sécurité routière (une courbe prononcée du chemin de fer se trouve à proximité), les deux quartiers ne sont pas

> - …*connectés* et ne le seront sans nul doute jamais.
> - …*reliés* et ne le seront sans nul doute jamais.
> - …*raccordés* et ne le seront sans nul doute jamais.

> Il n’y a pas de voie de raccordement possible permettant de relier les deux quartiers.

Je suis ouvert aux reformulations!

Merci.

Comment: J'écarterais *raccordés* comme ayant le sens trop technique (par exemple, quand on parle de tuyaux ou reseaux electriques.) *Reliés* me semble impliquer plus que une simple connection, ce qui nous porterait hors de contexte qui suit. Donc je dirais *connectés*. Mais je ne suis pas francophone.

Comment: @RogerVadim Merci Roger.

Comment: La considération de sécurité (courbe de la voie ferrée) interdit l'installation d'un passage à niveau reliant les deux quartiers. C'est peut-être évident, mais ça va mieux en le disant ;)

Comment: @XouDo Merci XouDo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Je dirais plutôt à la voix active: *Les deux quartiers ne communiquent pas*.

Comment: Oui, ou *Les deux quartiers sont isolés l'un l'autre.*

Comment: @jlliagre Merci encore jlliagre.

Comment: Ca peut effectivement vouloir dire que les quartiers ne sont pas (bien) reliés (comme on dirait de deux chambres qui communiquent ou pas), mais au sens figuré, on pourrait comprendre que ce sont les habitant qui ne communiquent pas.

Answer (score 1):

Les deux nouveaux quartiers en *construction* (*développement* n'est pas adapté aux activités des promoteurs ndr) dont je te parle sont situés dans la même zone urbaine, l’un étant situé au nord de l’autre. C’est le même promoteur qui est derrière ces deux éco-quartiers, l’un débouche sur la rue Notre-Monsieur et l’autre sur la rue St-Christian. Il existe une voie ferrée entre les deux, *mais* pour des *raisons de* sécurité *ferroviaire* (ça me parait plus logique ndr) (une courbe prononcée du chemin de fer se trouve à proximité), ces deux quartiers ne sont pas desservis (terme utilisé pour les trains ndr) et ne le seront sans doute jamais.

Comment: Le texte n’a carrément plus le même sens. Manifestement tu n’as pas compris ce que je cherchais à dire.

Comment: Ça n’a rien à voir avec la sécurité ferroviaire: il n’est juste pas possible de construire un passage à niveau, vu que ce serait trop dangereux pour les usagers de la route.

Comment: La courbe prononcée ne permet pas de voir arriver le train à l’avance, on peut l’entendre de loin, mais pas le voir. Voilà.

Comment: Ce qui fait que les deux quartiers sont isolés l’un l’autre (comme jilliagre dirait) ou ne communiquent pas (comme mouviciel a proposé).

Comment: En France, les passages à niveau sont protégés, qu'il y ait un virage ou pas ne change rien. Vous semblez pensez que tout le monde sait ce que vous voulez dire, sans le dire.

Comment: Pardonnez-moi, Necklondon. Au Québec les passages à niveau sont aussi protégés, mais il reste tout de même la possibilité (aussi faible soit-elle) qu’une barrière de sécurité soit défectueuse et qu’elle ne se déploie pas normalement. De fait, les autorités en matière de sécurité ferroviaire interdisent la construction d’un passage à niveau près d’un virage où cela pourrait être potentiellement plus dangereux.